# deriving types from an array of individually typed classes

Tags: c#, types

I'm trying to come up with the best way to pass multiple individually typed classes into a method. I won't know beforehand how many individually typed classes will be passed into the method so have started the code off like this...

**An Interface**

```
public interface ITypedClass {}
```

**A Typed Class**

```
public class TypedClass<T> : ITypedClass 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Output() {} 
}
```

**A Method**

```
public static void DoSomething(params ITypedClass[] typedClasses) {}
```

... and with these run something like the following, where the DoSomething method populates the typed classes with respective values based on the collective of what is passed into the DoSomething method.

```
var typedClassA = new TypedClass<TypeA>();
var typedClassB = new TypedClass<TypeB>();
...
var typedClassN = new TypedClass<TypeN>();

DoSomething(typedClassA, typedClassB, ... typedClassN etc

var valueA - typedClassA.Output();
var valueB - typedClassB.Output();
...
var valueN - typedClassN.Output();
```

Unfortunately inside the DoSomething method...

```
var typedClass = (TypedClass<T>)typedClasses.First();
```

... the individual values in the typedClasses parameter can't be converted back to TypedClass because the DoSomething method doesn't know what T is in each instance.

Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: You cannot use an unknown type at compile time.  You need to restate your problem in a way that can be expressed at compile time, or use lots of Reflection.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SLaks I'm asking the question because I'm aware that the way it's currently written doesn't work. The code segment at the end is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you planning to do with `valueA`, `valueB` etc?

Comment: @Thundter: Inside `DoSomething`, you can only work with non-generic types (or covariance).  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @Lee T will hold data retrieved/extrapolated in DoSomething

Comment: @SLaks DoSomething retrieves various result sets from from a third party cloud service. Data is passed in to the cloud service and we expect result sets of various types to come out, however the output of  the typedClass will be different if you pass in the same data but provide different valid types or even the same valid types in a different order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems a little bit obvious with more thought. Had to sleep on it a few nights before the obviousness finally clicked. Don't have DoSomething process the typed input, have TypedClass do it for you and instead have DoSomething split up the work.

**New Interface**

```
public interface ITypedClass 
{
    void Input(object value);
}
```

**New Typed Class**

The `Input` method here handles the conversion from object value to List value

```
public class TypedClass<T> : ITypedClass 
{
    public List<T> value;
    public void Input(object value) {...}
    public IEnumerable<T> Output() => value;
}
```

**New Method**

`DoSomething` now divides up the work...

```
public static void DoSomething(params ITypedClass[] typedClasses) 
{
    foreach (var c in typedClasses)
    {
        c.Input(...);
    }
}
```

Now when calling the following ...

```
var typedClassN = new TypedClass<TypeN>();
DoSomething(... typedClassN ... );
var valueN = typedClassN.Output();
```

`valueN` will have a value and `DoSomething` can handle a variable amount of typed classes